# Does the Media-Element on an Adaptive Card only support a specific MIME-Types/Formats?

Tags: microsoft-teams, mime-types, adaptive-cards

my goal is to create a very simple adaptive card, containing a media element. This media element should play different audio/video files streamed from my azure streaming service. Therefore I am using DASH/HLS as a Playback URL. I set the streaming URL displayed in Azure as the source of the media element and add application/x-mpegurl as the MIME-Type. I expected this to work as the same "settings" work in my ionic app using the videojs-player. But instead, nothing is displayed at all. This behaviour is easily reproduced using the adaptive [card desginer offered by MS][1]

Thanks a lot for the help!

My adaptive card json:

```
{
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Media",
      "id": "Exercise",
      "sources": [
        {
          "mimeType": "application/x-mpegurl",
          "url": "https://xxx.streaming.media.azure.net/GUID/xxx.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf)"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "version": "1.3"
}


  [1]: https://adaptivecards.io/designer/
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently media elements are not supported in Adaptive Cards.

https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference?branch=pr-en-us-5852#support-for-adaptive-cards

You can use Task Module to show an `<iframe>`-based widget such as a YouTube or Microsoft Stream video.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/what-are-task-modules